# Notice: Undefined variable: email_content

Tags: php, notice, mail-form

I have a contact form that is working at the moment,i only get two notices:

Notice: Undefined variable: email_content
Notice: Undefined variable: header

This is the code

```
// check if an error was found - if there was, send the user back to the form 
if (isset($error)) { 
$_POST['e'] = $error; 
} else {

// write the email content <-- HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
$email_content .= "Naam:" . htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES) . "\n\n"; 
$email_content .= "Tel:" . htmlspecialchars($tel, ENT_QUOTES) . "\n\n"; 
$email_content .= "E-mail:" . htmlspecialchars($email_address, ENT_QUOTES) . "\n\n"; 
$email_content .= "Onderwerp:" . htmlspecialchars($onderwerp, ENT_QUOTES) . "\n\n"; 
$email_content .= "Bericht:" . htmlspecialchars($message, ENT_QUOTES) . "\n\n"; 


/*
$email_content .= "Naam:$name\n\n"; 
$email_content .= "Tel:$tel\n\n"; 
$email_content .= "E-mail:$email_address\n\n"; 
$email_content .= "Onderwerp:$onderwerp\n\n"; 
$email_content .= "Bericht:$message\n\n";
*/ 
$header .= 'From: www.UTI.nl';   <-- AND HERE IS ALSO WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
// send the email 
mail ("robin2609@gmail.com", "Nieuw bericht van de UTI website", $email_content, $header );   <-- this is 

// send the user back to the form 
$_POST['s'] = 'Bedankt voor uw bericht.';
```

What am i missing? I hope you guys can help me.

Kind regards,

Robin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are trying to append to an undeclared string in `$email_content` & `$header`.

On your first lines of each variable change the `.=` to `=`

Comment: that did the trick, thank you for the fast response!

Answer (score 1):

You concatenate a string to an undefined variable:

```
$email_content .= "....";
```

Define it first by assigning something to it:

```
$email_content = "";
$email_content .= "....";
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `.=` (append string operand) on a string you didn't define yet. PHP sees this:

```
$string .= $string2
```

To mean this:

```
$string = $string . $string2
```

When it tries to parse that, `$string` doesn't exist so can't be concatenated with `$string2` or assigned to `$string`.

You should replace these lines:

```
$email_content .= "Naam:" . htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES) . "\n\n";
...
$header .= 'From: www.UTI.nl';   <-- AND HERE IS ALSO WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS
```

With the following:

```
$email_content = "Naam:" . htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES) . "\n\n";
...
$header = 'From: www.UTI.nl';
```

This should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You append a String to a undefined Variable.
Write

```
$header = "";
$email_content = "";
```

before you append sth. You would get an error in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

You are using this in your first line

```
$email_content .= "Naam:" . htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES) . "\n\n";
```

Which is interpreted as

```
$email_content = $email_content . "Naam:" . htmlspecialchars($name, ENT_QUOTES) . "\n\n";
```

SO it says undefined variable.

Remove '.' from the first lines of email_content and header variable

Might help!!

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize this variables. For example, in first lines.

```
$header = '';
$email_content = '';
```

Comment: I already got it working, thank you for your anwser!